# How to cause udisksctl to act for another user?

Tags: udev, d-bus, udisks

Logged in as the root user, `udisksctl mount` mounts my device at `/media/root/mydevice`. Alternately, logged in as another user, `udisksctl mount` mounts my device at `/media/anotheruser/mydevice`.

So far, so good. However, *I would like to mix the two.* Logged in as the root user, I would like `udisksctl mount` to mount my device at `/media/anotheruser/mydevice`. Reason: I want another user to be able to access my device.

In other words, logged in as root, I *think* that I want to do this: `udisksctl --user=anotheruser mount`. Unfortunately, `udisksctl` does not seem to have a `--user` option.

This does not work, either: `USER=anotheruser udisksctl mount`.

What should I do?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Logged in as the root user, the exact command I am issuing is `USER=thb udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda11`.

I have thought of making a setuid wrapper, but this would not help, would it? The point of issuing the command as root is to skip the GUI authentication dialog `udisksctl` otherwise pops up.

Is there perhaps some D-Bus technique that would help? I have not yet learned D-Bus well. At some stage in the control flow, whether at the Udisks stage, the D-Bus stage, or some other stage, I need to persuade the system to act for another user *without causing an unwanted GUI authentication dialog to pop up.*

This should be possible for the root user to do, shouldn't it?

My platform is Debian 8 jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, either

```
su -c 'udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdd --no-user-interaction' - thb
```

or

```
su - thb
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdd --no-user-interaction
exit
```

will mount `/dev/sdd` on e.g. `/media/thb/mydevice`
*without causing an unwanted GUI authentication dialog to pop up*.

Comment: This answer advances me toward my goal and is appreciated. Now the error message is `Error mounting /dev/sda11: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.NotAuthorizedCanObtain: Not authorized to perform operation`, which is an improvement. So, now I need to go learn polkit(8), which I do not know. Is this right?

Comment: @thb - Works fine on my system so yes, you need a polkit rule (or there's a polkit rule on your system that prevents you to mount on behalf of another user - check that first).

Comment: @thb - based on that error message, and if your system is using the old policykit libs you can find an example of polkit rule that should work on your system [in this thread](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=114466&start=15#p553199); for the new pokit libs the syntax is different (js) [see here](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie/issues/60)